# Angular 13 Typescript RegExp Date format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: angular, typescript

im working in Angular 13 project i want to create a directive to allow user only type numbers and '/' foor my date input. dd/mm/yyyy.
this is my Regx :

```
   if (!String(myVal).match(new RegExp(/^\d+$/))) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

this condition is working but i can type only numbers can't type / to format my date.
any suggestion to moify my Regx.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only type numbers with your Regex because `^\d+$` only allows numbers. If you're looking for a RegEx to validate the final date, it would look like this:

```
"01/06/2022".match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/)
```

Explanation:

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `\d{2}` matches exactly two digits
- `\d{4}` matches exactly four digits
- `\/` is an escaped forward slash (`/`), and you need to escape it
- `$` matches the end of the string
- You don't need to explicitly instantiate `new RegExp`, because that's done automatically when you define your Regex between the two `/`.

If you're looking for a Regex to only allow the typing of characters used in the date, it would look like this:

```
"01/06".match(/^[\d\/]+$/)
```

Read that as "only match if there's at least one (that's what the `+` means here) of the characters that are between `[` and `]`, that is: either digits (`\d`) or `/`".

And of course there are other ways to validate a date once it's fully typed, apart from a Regex (the Regex would permit dates like `99/99/9999`).

Comment: Validating dates is a whole other topic, you have to account for different countries.. Like US using some weird system where they put the month in first place.

Comment: One more thing I wanted to add: the reason you need to escape the slash (`/`) you want to match is that the Regex definition is also done between two slashes, so you escape the one that's inside (by adding a backslash before it) to tell JavaScript that you're not closing the Regex definition yet.